# JavaScript, где хранить ID, полученный от PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Генерирую страницу данными полученными запросом (php) с сервера.
Потом нужно передать ID пользователя, который получил PHP в JavaScript.

У меня в куках есть этот ID, можно ли его вытащить через JavaScript? или как-то по другому это делается?

Проще говоря, нужно что бы при окончании генерирования страницы, PHP отдал имеющийся у него ID пользователя в JavaScript, а с JS я уже делаю AJAX запросы и т.д

Comment: > , который получил PHP в JavaScript.

Поставьте запятую после "PHP", а то не ясно как это "PHP получил в JavaScript".

> У меня в куках есть этот ID, можно ли его вытащить через JavaScript?


http://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно достать из кука данные с помощью JS

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
    var c = ca[i].trim();
    if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Смысл понял, спасибо